# What type of energy consumption is indicated with the power rating of a device

Tags: power, power-electronics, power-meter

For example, I have a 36W LED unit.

If I needed to measure with a electricity meter, would 36W be active, reactive, or  apparent power consumption?

I would appreciate if you could tell me (if there is any) what International Standard is followed to print out the values and all necessary indications (active, reactive, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power rating of a device is the maximum power and is usually given in watts for real power and volt-amperes for apparent power for AC systems. Also not uncommon is the indication of active power and power factor.

DC power will always be a real power value, as there's no such thing as real/reactive power in a DC circuit. (That could be the case with above mentioned LED device, if DC power ratings are given.)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that DC power will always be a real power value, as there's no such thing as real/reactive power in a DC circuit.